# update to Ubuntu 20.10 failed due to Package dependencies cannot be resolved: grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: grub2, updates, uefi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Dell XPS-15 and I install updates whenever they are available. Today I was notified about an update, tried to install with update package and came back with the message:

Package dependencies cannot be resolved

grub-efi-amd64-signed:

I'm at a loss, never seen this before. Can anyone be of assistance.

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894264/unable-to-upgrade-grub-efi-amd64-signed)

Comment: Emil, that appears to have worked. Although "grub" has been replaced on 20.10, that's what system informed me  when trying to reinstall. Updates have been installed and it appears to be ok. Not clear why this happened. Thanks. David

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to upgrade grub-efi-amd64-signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894264/unable-to-upgrade-grub-efi-amd64-signed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Software Updater error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKHkM.jpg)

Added a screenshot of the error message.

Note that you can simply deselect the entry for the:-

"GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)"

...in the Software Updater window to have the rest of the updates (new kernel, etc) install successfully.

Additional Info:-  In my case I'm running Ubuntu MATE 20.10 with a ZFS root on an HP 15S (AMD Ryzen 5-4500U)